# C# - How get the instance where a MethodInfo come from?

Tags: c#, object, instance, methodinfo

I read that MethodInfo only have information only about the method, nothing about the instance that come from, but there is some trick to the get instance to invoke the method as part of that instance?

For example:

```
MethodInfo someMethodInfo;

var obj = GetMethodInstance(someMethodInfo);
someMethodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The MethodInfo is not associated with any Instance, it discovers the attributes of a method and provides access to method metadata.

> The [MethodInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netframework-4.7.1) class represents a method of a type. You can use a MethodInfo object to obtain information about the method that the object represents and to invoke the method.

MethodInfo is reflected directly from the Type definition, and as such has no relationship to any particular instance of the type, infact to get the Method Info you must generally get the type either directly with `typeof()` (so without even having an instance) or by first getting the type definition from `obj.GetType()`. 
So already the type definition is divorced from the original instance before you even attempt to get the MethodInfo, hence it would be harder again to obtain the original instance, if there was an instance at all to get.

Check if you can workaround using Delegates, otherwise look at the process where you obtain the methodinfo, and at that time pass through `this` to keep a reference to the object so that you don't have to try looking for it in the first place.